# Why are synthetic Auxins capable of killing dicots such as weeds at high concentration but do not cause damage to monocots?

Tags: plant-physiology

I read that synthetic auxins like 2,4-D and 2,4,5-T can be used as herbicides against dicots but they don't affect monocots. Can someone explain how they damage dicots and not damage monocots

Comment: A similar, if not identical, [question was answered in 2015](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20006/why-doesnt-the-herbicide-2-4-d-damage-lawn-grass).